# Samba4 - detect password change

Tags: password, samba4

I want to detect when a user changes his password on the Samba4 DC.
As far as i know Samba4 stores the passwords in `/var/lib/samba/private/secrets.tdb`.
But when I change a password with smbpasswd the file does not change, the last change date is unchanged and the md5sum is the same.

So how can i detect if a password was changed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Samba 4.x in domain controller mode stores the entire user account information in its built-in directory service database (not to be confused with a filesystem directory), very much like Windows DCs do.

The directory can be accessed with LDAP protocol, so you can use `ldapsearch` command to query account information, including *pwdLastSet* attribute. However be aware that this attribute may not be replicated between DCs, in this case you should query all of them separately.

Comment: Thanks, with that hint i solved my problem
For those interested in `ldapsearch -h localhost -p 389 -x -D "CN=username,CN=Users,DC=ACME,dc=com" -y ldap.credentials -b "CN=Users,DC=ACME,DC=com" -s one '(mail=*@ACME.com)' | grep "pwdLastSet: " | md5sum` did the job for me